# Transferring asci map string to int map array

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, integer, 2d

Hi I am currently trying to convert this string to a usable 2D int Array.

```
String samplemap = 
            "-------------------\n" +
            "|K *  P  *       D|\n" +
            "|  *     *        |\n" +
            "|  *     ******   |\n" +
            "|     *           |\n" +
            "-------------------";
```

My goal is to break down the samplemap string, to transfer over the object locations such as K(0,4) *[(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(6,1),(8,2),(9,2),(10,2),(11,2),(12,2),(13,2)] P(6,4) D(17,4)

I have currently can get the RowNum and ColNum

```
 int maxRow = samplemap.split("\n").length - 2;
 int maxCol = samplemap.split("\n")[0].length() - 2;
```

I pass these int to my FloorMap class to build the map and fill it with 0's. Later hopefully by somehow parsing the above I can set each object inside the FloorMap as a (x,y) cord and be represented by an ID (K = 1 , P = 2, * = 3 and D = 4).

My current logic is this...

```
//Find "*" in the samplemap to pass to the constructor in floor class
        // * - wall - 4
        for(int i = 1; i < maxRow; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j < maxCol; j++) {
                if(samplemap.split("\n")[i].charAt(j) == '*') {
                    floorMap.setWallLocation(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
Output: 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 4 4 4 4 4 4 0 0
```

While we're here is there a way to assign a pointer (Facing up) for each K ( = 1) as in if moving through the int map in a way where only if facing forward I am able to move.
ex:
K(0,4) Facing: UP
Turn Right (Pointing towards wall) (Can't move forward)
Turn Right (Pointing towards empty) (Can move forward)

First time posting on here, any help and guidance is welcomed. Starting to get back into coding after 5 years of collage.

Comment: _"While we're here..."_ Focus on one question at a time. Asking multiple questions results in muddled answers and no clear subject for the question.

Comment: Are you building a map that map character to (row, col)?  Why does your input need to include horizontal and vertical lines?  Is that supposed to be visual borders to the human user?  Can the input be without horizontal or vertical lines?

Comment: Yes it serves as visual input. Briefly explained it in the “while we’re here..” the input could be without the lines. As the 0’s represent just the white space in between the borders. 17 white space for col and 4 white space for rows 

In my int maxRow logic this removes the outer lines treating them as padding.